# Cases behaving in a very eccentric manner

Tags: align, cases

I'd be very glad if someone can tell me why is cases behaving ridiculously in the following code.

```
\begin{align}
I^*= \begin{cases} 
0, & \left(\mathbb{E}\left[\theta_c|C=1\right] < \theta_i \ \
\text{and} \ \  \mathbb{E}\left[\max\left\{\theta_i,\theta_c\right\}|C=1\right] <
\frac{c_I}{\gamma}\right) \\ 
0, & \left(\mathbb{E}\left[\theta_c|C=1\right] \geq 
\theta_i \ \ \text{and} \ \  \mathbb{E}\left[\max\left\ 
\theta_i,\theta_c\right\}|C=1\right] < \frac{c_I}{\gamma}\right) \\ 
\left[0,1\right], & \left(\mathbb{E}\left[\theta_c|C=1\right] < \theta_i \ \ 
\text{and} \ \  \mathbb{E}\left[\max\left\{\theta_i,\theta_c\right\}|C=1\right] = 
\frac{c_I} {\gamma}\right) \\ 
\left[0,1\right], & \left(\mathbb{E}\left[\theta_c|C=1\right] \geq 
\theta_i \ \ \text{and} \ \  \mathbb{E}\left[\max\left\
{\theta_i,\theta_c\right\}|C=1\right] = \frac{c_I}{\gamma}\right) \\ 
1, \left(\mathbb{E}\left[\theta_c|C=1\right] < \theta_i \ \ \text{and} \ \  
\mathbb{E}\left[\max\left\{\theta_i,\theta_c\right\}|C=1\right] > \frac{c_I}
{\gamma}\right) \\ 
1, \left(\mathbb{E}\left[\theta_c|C=1\right] \geq \theta_i \ \ 
\text{and} \ \  \mathbb{E}\left[\max\left\{\theta_i,\theta_c\right\}|C=1\right] > 
\frac{c_I}{\gamma}\right) 
\end{cases} 
\end{align}
```

The code looks like this:
[image]
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Your code is not minimal. If you tried to reduce it, you would see that you are missing `&` on the last two lines of `cases`.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thank you. Missing &'s were the problem indeed. Cheers :)

Comment: a better strategy for adding spaces around "and" is to include them in the `\text`: `\text{ \ and \ }` or even `\quad` instead of the doubled "single space".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `&` after `1,` in the last two lines of the code:

```
\begin{equation}
I^*= \begin{cases} 
0, & \text{if }
\mathbb{E}[\theta_c\mid C=1] < \theta_i
\text{ and }
\mathbb{E}[\max\{\theta_i,\theta_c\} \mid C=1] < \frac{c_I}{\gamma}
\\ 
0, & \text{if }
\mathbb{E}[\theta_c \mid C=1] \geq \theta_i 
\text{ and }
\mathbb{E}[\max\{\theta_i,\theta_c\} \mid C=1] < \frac{c_I}{\gamma}
\\ 
[0,1], & \mathbb{E}[\theta_c \mid C=1] < \theta_i 
\text{ and }
\mathbb{E}[\max\{\theta_i,\theta_c\} \mid C=1] = \frac{c_I}{\gamma}
\\ 
[0,1], & \text{if }
\mathbb{E}[\theta_c \mid C=1] \geq \theta_i
\text{ and }
\mathbb{E}[\max\{\theta_i,\theta_c\} \mid C=1] = \frac{c_I}{\gamma}
\\ 
1, & \text{if }
\mathbb{E}[\theta_c \mid C=1] < \theta_i
\text{ and }
\mathbb{E}[\max\{\theta_i,\theta_c\} \mid C=1] > \frac{c_I}{\gamma}
\\
1, & \text{if }
\mathbb{E}[\theta_c \mid C=1] \geq \theta_i 
\text{ and }
\mathbb{E}[\max\{\theta_i,\theta_c\} \mid C=1] > \frac{c_I}{\gamma}
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}
```

Please note that I made some more changes to improve things, namely I removed the outer parentheses, put `if` to each line, removed the unnecessary spaces around `and` (and put them inside the `\text{...}`, but this is not necessary), I removed all the spurious `\left...\right` and I changed `|` to `\mid` to get the proper spacing.

(I hope I didn't mess anything up, I can't test the code now.)

Comment: This looks indeed much better (i tested). Thank you very much.

Comment: @firemind You're welcome. Actually, I just realized that the `,` before `&` are spurious, too. It makes the perfect English and mathematical sense without them.